# Pyspark --- adding new column with values per group by

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, pyspark

Suppose I have the following data set:

```
a | b   
1 | 0.4 
1 | 0.8 
1 | 0.5 
2 | 0.4
2 | 0.1
```

I would like to add a new column called "label" where the values are determined locally for each group of values in **a**. The highest value of **b** in a group **a** is labeled 1 and all others are labeled 0.

The output would look like this :

```
a | b   | label
1 | 0.4 | 0
1 | 0.8 | 1
1 | 0.5 | 0
2 | 0.4 | 1
2 | 0.1 | 0
```

How can I do this efficiently using PySpark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with window functions. First you'll need a couple of imports:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, row_number, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

and window definition:

```py
w = Window().partitionBy("a").orderBy(desc("b"))
```

Finally you use these:

```py
df.withColumn("label", when(row_number().over(w) == 1, 1).otherwise(0))
```

For example data:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 0.4), (1, 0.8), (1, 0.5), (2, 0.4), (2, 0.1)
]).toDF(["a", "b"])
```

the result is:

```
+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|label|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|0.8|    1|
|  1|0.5|    0|
|  1|0.4|    0|
|  2|0.4|    1|
|  2|0.1|    0|
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: So what order should your code lines be run in -- as follows? from..., parallelize, window(), withColumn?